# Comment traduire « combover »?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Tout est dans le titre, je cherche le mot français correspondant à « *[combover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_over)* ».

Comment: Were you inspired by [SMBC](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2360#comic)?

Comment: Totally :) [The french translation of the comics](http://cereales.lapin.org/index.php?comms=yes&number=2208) uses the more general "une coiffure pourrie".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'existe pas de mot équivalent en français, il faut faire une périphrase du genre ***« cheveux peignés pour cacher la calvitie »***.

Answer (score 4):

La mèche longue ? On trouve aussi la forme "la longue mèche".

Comment: Ça implique vraiment une calvitie qu'on cherche à cacher ? Pour moi, une mèche longue, c'est une mèche qui est longue et c'est tout.

Comment: J'emploie ce terme, mes amis aussi, mais est ce que c'est une pratique locale ? je ne sais pas car on a peu l'occasion de l'utiliser.

Answer (score 4):

Je m'étais moi même posé la question il y a quelques années et, comme le dit F'x, la conclusion est qu'il n'existe pas de traduction "parfaite".

Mais l'une des meilleures options à l'époque était sans doute:

> coiffure [à la] [Giscard](http://images-booknode.com/author_cover_valery_giscard_d_estaing_6196_250_350)

... du nom du plus célèbre porteur de "combover" français.

Néanmoins, cette référence tend probablement à perdre de sa résonance, à mesure que l'intéressé disparaît complètement de la scène publique (d'autant plus que je crois qu'il a finalement renoncé à la-dite coupe, depuis les années 90, en faveur d'une calvitie assumée). Je pense que c'est une expression qui parlerait surtout aux personnes de 30 ans et plus. Peut-être pourrait on la mettre au goût du jour en utilisant [Houellebecq](http://www.theenthusiast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/michelhouellebecq.jpg)?

Comment: Déjà Giscard, je ne vois que vaguement qui c'est, mais Houellebecq pas du tout... Je sais que mon incultance dépasse l'entendure, mais quand même, c'est fort français comme référence.

Comment: @Joubarc: c'est 100% français (faute de mieux ou plus universel). Cela dit: 1) Giscard est quand même l'un des 6 présidents de la Ve République: *à une époque*, son profile était probablement aussi célèbre que n'importe quel autre chef d'état. 2) Houellebecq (goûts personnels entièrement mis à part) est objectivement l'un des écrivains francophones (*contemporains*) le plus vendu dans le monde de nos jours. Et clairement l'un des plus "reconnaissables" en France. Bref, l'un ou l'autre constituerait une référence tout à fait immédiate pour une large partie de la population française...

Comment: Giscard, je l'ai déjà vu en photo, mais de là à comprendre la référence, non (et pourtant j'ai vécu sous sa présidence). Houellebecq, je connais de nom mais je n'ai aucune idée d'à quoi il ressemble.

Comment: C'est pour ça que Houellebecq ne me disait rien, je cherchais en politique. Mais c'est vrai, ils parlent de lui aux grosses tête, maintenant qu'on en parle.